# Setting Terminal Color in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

So, I've been looking around at printing colored text in python. I've seen plenty of ways to print colors on a per-line basis, but I can't find anything on how to change the text color of the whole terminal (similar to how you can in command prompt.) How, if possible, would I accomplish this?

I tried using win32api.SetSysColors, but I'm not sure that has anything to do with the terminal.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/colorama/

Comment: Not every terminal will have this capability.

Comment: Note: there is a line mode, and a screen mode on terminals. `curses` module on standard library is used to switch on second mode. You may see different behaviour on scrollbar in such mode). But for more control, your program should start a windows which you can display as a new terminal.

Comment: Have you seen [textualize/rich](https://github.com/Textualize/rich)?